# Center WPF RibbonWindow Title via XAML Code

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, ribbon, title

I've found some info on `StackOverflow` regarding my problem, so I introduced the following `XAML` code to my window.
Now everything is fine, while the `WPF` window hasn't quick launch icons or contextual tabs active.

Is there a way to center the application title completely via `XAML` Code.

```xml
<ribbon:Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ActualWidth}">ApplicationTitle
            <TextBlock.Effect>
               <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="MintCream " BlurRadius="10"/>   
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>           
</ribbon:Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
```

Comment: +1 I've been trying to figure out a way around the horrible default title template that `RibbonWindow` comes with. This has got me a workaround. I see the problem you're having with the Quick Access Toolbar and contextual tabs, however.

Comment: Looking into the visual tree of the window the title part ends up being inside a `DockPanel`. As far as I'm aware, they don't offer that much layout functionality.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the ribbon uses a `RibbonTitlePanel` with a proprietary layout algorithm that places the title to the right of any contextual tabs. I guess you could derive a class from `RibbonTitlePanel` and provide a better layout algorithm, but to hook it into the `Ribbon` control you then need to modify the `Ribbon` control template, and just getting a copy of that template seems to be a hard task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very naïve way to do it. It comes about from inspecting the visual tree of a `RibbonWindow` and its concomitant `Ribbon`. I've been playing with this code for a couple of hours (and no longer) -- it's a bit rough around the edges and I'm not sure it's completely bug free. There's some optimizations to be made and it should be noted that I suck at WPF; there might be better way to do things.

For what it's worth the code is below, but note first:

- The references to the `PART_Icon` template are not directly related to your question, but it is related to the aesthetics of the window.
- The references to `IsWin8OrHigher` and `FindChild` are in classes that I'll include at the end. My interest in Windows 8 is that the native ribbon library centres the title text, whereas earlier versions of Windows do not. I'm trying to emulate that here.
- I have no idea how the `RibbonWindow` was shipped with Visual Studio 2012 in its current iteration. The rendering on Windows 8 looks pretty miserable. After all this, I'm tempted to overload `TitleTemplate` with a `TextBlock` to get rid of the default glow and leave it at that.
- The `RibbonWindow` doesn't look very good maximized, customization or not.

When I started writing this code, this was approximately what I was aiming for:

[image]

For comparison, this is how the `RibbonWindow` renders itself with no customisation:

[image]

This is how it renders with `TitleTemplate` defined to a `TextBlock` with `TextAlignment="Center"` but otherwise without any fancy text effects:

[image]

With the code below, we get this result:

[image]

MainWindow:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Environment.OSVersion.IsWin8OrHigher()) {
            SizeChanged += (sender, args) => TitleHack();
            Activated += (sender, args) => TitleHack();
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        if (!Environment.OSVersion.IsWin8OrHigher())
            return;
        var icon = GetTemplateChild("PART_Icon") as Image;
        if (icon == null)
            return;
        icon.Margin = new Thickness(icon.Margin.Left + 3, icon.Margin.Top + 2,
                                    icon.Margin.Right, icon.Margin.Bottom);
    }

    private void TitleHack() {
        var ribbonTitlePanel = MyRibbon.FindChild<FrameworkElement>("PART_TitlePanel");
        var qatTopHost = MyRibbon.FindChild<FrameworkElement>("QatTopHost");
        var titleHost = MyRibbon.FindChild<FrameworkElement>("PART_TitleHost");
        var tabGroup = MyRibbon.FindChild<FrameworkElement>("PART_ContextualTabGroupItemsControl");

        var qatTopHostLeft = qatTopHost.TransformToAncestor(ribbonTitlePanel).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).X;
        var tabGroupLeft = tabGroup.TransformToAncestor(ribbonTitlePanel).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).X;

        var width = ribbonTitlePanel.ActualWidth;

        if (tabGroup.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) {
            width -= tabGroup.ActualWidth;
            width -= tabGroupLeft - qatTopHostLeft;
        } else {
            width -= qatTopHost.ActualWidth;
        }

        if (ResizeMode != ResizeMode.NoResize && WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
            width -= 48; // For the min and max buttons

        titleHost.Width = width > 0 ? width : Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

OperatingSystemExtensionMethods.cs:

```cs
public static class OperatingSystemExtensionMethods {
    private static readonly Version Windows8Version = new Version(6, 2);

    public static bool IsWin8OrHigher(this OperatingSystem that) {
        if (that.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT)
            return false;
        return that.Version.CompareTo(Windows8Version) >= 0;
    }
}
```

DependencyObjectExtensionMethods.cs:

```cs
public static class DependencyObjectExtensionMethods {
    public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject that, string elementName)
        where T : FrameworkElement {
        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(that);

        for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(that, i);
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;

            if (frameworkElement != null && elementName == frameworkElement.Name)
                return (T) frameworkElement;

            if ((frameworkElement = frameworkElement.FindChild<T>(elementName)) != null)
                return (T) frameworkElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be working fine. I've just tested it and the title centers as it should.

Comment: i you haven't got any contextual tabs active it is fine, but with contextual tabs active it centers to the rest of width beginning at the end of the contextual tab. I'am searching for solution which centers to the whole title bar in any case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it truly centered, it needs to be:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
```