# How can I center the title of a WPF RibbonWindow?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I want to center the title of my RibbonWindow, and not have it aligned on the side.

This thread said it had an answer:
[Center WPF RibbonWindow Title via XAML Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345422/center-wpf-ribbonwindow-title-via-xaml-code/12959073#12959073)

but it didn't work.

Bellow is an image and the corresponding code.

[image: title not centered]

```
    <RibbonWindow x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon>
            <Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ActualWidth}">ApplicationTitle
                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="MintCream " BlurRadius="10"   />
                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
            </Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
    </RibbonWindow>
```

I am using VS 2012, with .NET 4.5 and the included System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ElementName` in the binding (`Width="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ActualWidth}"`) needs to match the name of the RibbonWindow.  So, in this case you need "Window" for the name:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="Window1" x:Name="Window"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 4):

Had a bad experience with using RibbonControlsLibrary for WPF. It has issues not only around title centering. It also breaks window rounding corners at the top, icon and title goes out of the screen when maximized, and personally I haven't found any chance to program ribbon group dialog. All of this lead me to searching for an alternative, and I have found a [Fluent Ribbon Controls Suite](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)

Download source code and build it for .NET 4.5 (I did it with absolutely no issues).